# Error in Heat Equation Matlab Code

Tags: matlab

```
t_comp=0.02;
dx=0.05;
dt=0.001;
x = linspace(0,1,dx); 
t = linspace(0,t_comp,dt);
N=length(t);
M=length(x);
u=[];
u(1,:)=sin(2.*pi.*x);
u(:,1)=0;
u(:,M)=0;
for i=1:1:N-1
  for j=2:1:M-1
    u(i+1,j)=(A.*u(i,j-1)+B.*u(i,j)+c.*u(i,j+1));
  end
end    
plot(x,u(1,:))
```

I'm facing some errors in this code. I wrote the heat equation and inserted the boundary and initial conditions. So what's wrong with the code.

Comment: What errors are you getting? And what are A and B?

Comment: when i run the code this error appears

Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

Error in ex3 (line 11)
u(:,M)=0;

A, B and C are constants = 1

Comment: You should always pre-allocate your matrix and not write  `u=[];`

Comment: How to pre-allocate... can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is caused by the fact that `M` is 0, this happens because `x` is an array of length 0, this is due to the misuse of `linspace`.

[linspace](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html) when used as follows: `linspace(x1, x2, n)` generates an array of length `n` of equally spaced points from x1 to x2, in your case n is 0.05 and is rounded down to 0.

I think what you meant was `x = 0:dx:1;`, this will generate an array that goes from 0 to 1 in 0.05 steps.

you have the same problem in this line: `t = linspace(0,t_comp,dt);`

Comment: I have a question?
the code is running but when i change t_comp or dt, every time it gives me the same plot. Is that right?

Comment: Your plot is only looking at the first row of `u`, it is not dependent on `t` at all